# Error: Called before initialization while using { t } translation strings in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using translation string in my react project, and want to convert this constants.js file with hardcoded strings to translation strings. But it throws error to be specefic this line
const { t } = getI18N(); throws an error Error: Called before initialization.
So the code works in all the index.hs files i have achieved the translation strings just the respective constants.js file that i created earlier have some hardcoded strings that i need to convert into translation strings.

constants.js file that throws error ->

```
import { getI18N } from '../../i18N';
const { t } = getI18N();
export const PAGE_TYPE = {
  GOLD_RATE: 'GOLD',
  SILVER_RATE: 'SILVER',
};

export const PAGE_ENTITY_TYPE = {
  [PAGE_TYPE.GOLD_RATE]: 'GOLD',
  [PAGE_TYPE.SILVER_RATE]: 'SILVER',
};

export const PAGE_TITLES = {
  [PAGE_TYPE.GOLD_RATE]: 'Gold Rate',
  [PAGE_TYPE.SILVER_RATE]: 'Silver Rate',
};

export const PAGE_UNITS = {
  [PAGE_TYPE.GOLD_RATE]: 'kt',
  [PAGE_TYPE.SILVER_RATE]: '',
};
```

my implementation of the file that gives { t } for translation

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import config from '../config';
import en from './translations/en.json';
import es from './translations/es.json';
import pt from './translations/pt.json';
import hi from './translations/hi.json';

let i18N;

export function getI18N() {
  if (!i18N) {
    throw new Error('Called before initialization');
  }
  return i18N;
}

export default function i18NInit() {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href.split('?')[1]);
  const languageCode = searchParams.get('languageCode') || 'en';

  i18n
    // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
    .use(initReactI18next)
    // init i18next
    // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
    .init({
      debug: config.env === 'development',
      lng: languageCode,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
      },
      resources: {
        en: {
          translation: en,
        },
        es: {
          translation: es,
        },
        pt: {
          translation: pt,
        },
        hi: {
          translation: hi,
        },
      },
    });

  i18N = i18n;
}
```

previous is the i18n code thats created by my peer and so ig there is some mistake I making in my constants.js code to translate
basically the strings are written in this format
`{t(‘str’)}`

inside en.json

```
{
 “Str”: “this is a translation string”
}
```